# Jenkins Pipeline DSL: Can I conditionally retry an entire stage?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Sometimes our Jenkins stage fails with the following error:

```
Emulator did not finish booting within 600 seconds, aborting
```

This usually happens because the VM has entered some type of low memory state and any subsequent attempts to boot the emulator on that VM will failure. So in this scenario, I'd like to automatically re-execute the entire stage as a whole (should hopefully automatically be assigned a new VM). How can I achieve this?

There's `options { retry(3) }`

```
stage("android-ui-tests") {
  options {
    retry(3) 
  }
  steps {
      // run stage..
  }
}
```

But AFAIK, this is not conditional. An API like the following would be ideal:

```
options {
  retry(3) {
    if(exception.contains("Emulator did not finish booting")) {
      // `true` to retry
      return true
    }
    return false
  } 
}
```

Does anything like this exist? Or maybe a post condition that could inspect the failure and trigger a retry?

Comment: I do not believe you can retry an entire stage. This does sound more like a configuration management/monitoring problem though. If you are doing immutable infrastructure, then these build agents could be replaced after failing the health check.